# Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory(buildstatus) without url decoding for private Jenkins running in ECS

Tags: nginx, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecs, nginx-reverse-proxy

1. Jenkins running in an AWS ECS(private)
2. Repos are in github enterprise cloud.

So to trigger repos from jenkins we setup public nginx ECS infront (WAF-whitelisted only github IPs) as reverse proxy

nginx reverse-proxy(Public ECS) -> WAF(Whitelisted github IPs) -> Jenkins(Private ECS)

Now build-status for each job is not coming up, I need to replace the existing build-status url code from %2f to %252f.

[image: https://github.com/jenkinsci/embeddable-build-status-plugin#job]

Any option nginx has to do url decoding so that I don't need to replace each URLs from readme file from 100+ repos ?

Nginx configuration used is below

```html
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /github-webhook {
            proxy_pass https://jenkins-sandbox.io/github-webhook;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75;
            proxy_send_timeout 300;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            send_timeout 300;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on; # Determines whether the connection with a proxied server should be closed when a client closes the connection without waiting for a response.
        }
        # location /buildStatus(.*)$ {
        #     proxy_pass https://jenkins-sandbox.io/$1;
        #     proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #     add_header Content-Type image/svg+xml;
        # }
        location /buildStatus/ {
            rewrite ^ $request_uri;
            rewrite ^/buildStatus/(.*) $1 break;
            return 400;
            proxy_pass https://jenkins-sandbox.io/$uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75;
            proxy_send_timeout 300;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            send_timeout 300;
            add_header Content-Type image/svg+xml;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on; # Determines whether the connection with a proxied server should be closed when a client closes the connection without waiting for a response.
        }
    }
}
```